# push to Array in async function is not filtered

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, arraylist, async-await

```
var listUsers= [];
for(let item of list){
        var profile = await getOne(item.updatedBy);
        var gettedUsers = await User.find(queryData).populate({path: "profiles"});
        var users = gettedUsers.filter(user => user._id !== profile._id);
            if(users) {
                for(let gettedUser of users) {
                    if(!listUsers.includes(gettedUser.profile._id)){
                        listUsers.push(gettedUser.profile._id);
                        // do some stuff for the getted user
                    }
                }
            }
}
console.log(listUsers); // i get duplicated users
```

I had added this array list 'listUsers' to filter users and then for each one of them i can do some stuff, but the problem is that i get duplicated users.
Someone could help me ?

Comment: Try to console.log every push, maybe you will track the error.

Comment: Thanks @sonic , that's how I solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is  that I changed :

```
listUsers.includes(gettedUser.profile._id)
```

to :

```
var contains = (list, element) => list.some(elem =>{
    return JSON.stringify(element) === JSON.stringify(elem);
     });
```

I really don't know waht's the problem but i think I was comparing objects instead of strings. Anyway this solved it ;)

Comment: It depends what was under `_id`. there was some answer pointing out that you are comparing objects but when I asked if this is a number the author of answer just deleted the answer... I am happy you have solved the problem.